# How to locate position and get intermediate results in the source code on VTM?

Tags: video-compression

I want to achieve deep learning-based video compression. But it's difficult to get the intermediate results. So I want to ask if there are some convenient methods.

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify your question 'intermediate results'?

If you mean reconstructed frame of VTM, you can get a buffer from picture class.

**EncGOP** encodes every frame in GOP and executes in-loop filters, therefore you can get intermediate frame from **EncGOP** while encoding.

At decoder side, you can get same buffer at **DecLib**.

I hope this answer helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to replace one module like quantization with neural network. Therefore I need data to train and I think intermediate result is necessary.